# Drag and Drop set value forms

Tags: angularjs, drag-n-drop, angular5

У меня есть Drag and Drop

Код:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-murdock-psr1d?file=/src/app/app.component.html)

Надо реализовать чтоб при перетаскивании с левого поля Drag and Drop в правое данные сетились в форму! Когда нажимал сабмит оны собирались!
Проблема состоит в том что когда я делаю инициализацию в

> drop(event: CdkDragDrop){}

то данные сетяться во все формы с последнего перетаскиваемого элемента!
Тоесть если :

```
 drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
  moveItemInArray(
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex
  );
} else {
  console.log(event.item.data);
  transferArrayItem(
    event.previousContainer.data,
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex
  );
}
this.invoiceForms = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl(event.item.data.id, Validators.required),
  name: new FormControl(event.item.data.name, Validators.required),
  price: new FormControl(event.item.data.price, Validators.required),
  discount: new FormControl(0, Validators.required),
  description: new FormControl(event.item.data.description, Validators.required)
});
}
```

То все данные засетяться с посл. формы во все остальные!Полагаю что проблема состоит в том что formcontrolname у всех формах одны и теже , как мне задать уникалные formControl в компоненте и при ините формы?